# QWebEngineView Consuming Events Preventing Tab Switching, Shortcuts and other events from mainloop

Tags: qt, qwebengineview

I'm facing an issue in my Qt application where i replaced one view from QTextEdit to a QWebEngineView within a QTabWidget.
It seems that QWebEngineView to be blocking events. The problem is evident when attempting to switch tabs using both mouse clicks and shortcuts like Ctrl+Tab. It appears that the QWebEngineView is capturing these events, preventing normal tab switching.

Furthermore, essential shortcuts like Ctrl+F for find functionality are no longer functioning as expected. I've tried event filters and focus management techniques, but the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation? How can I ensure proper event propagation and regain control over tab switching and shortcuts when using QWebEngineView? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: SOLVED!! problem was i used mainWindow.show() before i added widgets to it